# Decay scheme of sodium-24

Tags: physical-chemistry, nuclear-chemistry

Sodium-24 decays into an excited nucleus of magnesium-24. Magnesium reaches nuclear ground level via two consecutive gamma emissions. What are the half-lives (time scales) for these two processes? I think that those gamma photons are emitted very rapidly after Mg-24 is formed. I'm curious to know but I cannot find data. I'm a Chem undergrad with interests in nuclear chemistry.

[image: picture]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_isomer suggests that if it's usual de-excitation, then it's on order of picoseconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For energy levels in nuclei (and their gamma emission) the first place to look is at the Evaluated Nuclear Structure Data Files. I usually use the [Brookhaven](https://www.nndc.bnl.gov/ensdf/) site, but there may be a closer mirror to you. Enter 24 into the Nuclide or Mass box and hit Enter. Check the 'Adopted Levels, Gamma' box by $^{24}$Mg, and request the pdf version (back up at the top).

On the last page you will find the lower levels like this (although rotated by 90 degrees):

[image: 24Mg gamma levels]

So, the 4122.889 keV level has a decay time of 22 fs - this is the level that the first gamma decays from. The 1368.672 keV level has a decay time of 1.33 ps - this is the second gamma in your sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You can estimate the lifetime from the classical equation for radiative decay rate constant , $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\tau}= \frac{(e\omega)^2 }{6\pi\epsilon_0m_ec^3}$ where $\omega$ is the frequency (Hz), $m_e$ electron mass and $\epsilon_0$ the permittivity of free space.

This value gives a lower limit (i.e. fastest possible value)  on the lifetime $\tau$, and this works out in the region of $\approx 4\cdot 10^{-14}$ s or $40$ fs for the 2.76 Mev transition. This formula is somewhat simpler than calculating the dipole vector integral and Einstein coefficients, and produces lifetimes that are equal to or larger than the classical value.